# How to put variables in a SQL Server comment?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, comments, mysql-variables

Sadly, we do auditing through inline comments in SQL queries, like this:

```
begin transaction; 
EXEC someStoredProcedure; --this was executed by Bob
commit transaction;
```

I'm trying to automate it by making a tool with user inputted fields. Is there any way to make strings in a comment variable, like this?

```
DECLARE @username varchar(50);

begin transaction; 
EXEC someStoredProcedure; --this was executed by @username
commit transaction;
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL will allow that.

Comment: What are you imagining would be the use of this?   I can't picture what you're really trying to do here.   So you would type `@username` in the comment?   What's the point?

Answer (score 1):

You can use in this way, you need to assign system_user and use procedure name as variable.

```
declare @username varchar(50) = system_user, @procname varchar(50) = '[dbo].[Checkforproc]' 

begin 
exec (@procname)
print ('this '+@procname+ ' was executed by ' +@username)
end
```

Then you can see your message in this way.

[image]